# Value...should NOT have additional properties

Tags: eslint

In my ESLint configuration file (`eslintrc.json`), I have the following rule:

```json
// ...
"no-underscore-dangle": [
  "error",
  {
    "enforceInMethodNames": true,
    "allowFunctionParams": false
  }
],
// ...
```

Contrary to what the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-underscore-dangle#options) seems to suggest, it causes the following error:

```
Error: .eslintrc.json:
        Configuration for rule "no-underscore-dangle" is invalid:
        Value {"enforceInMethodNames":true,"allowFunctionParams":false,"allowAfterThis":false,"allowAfterSuper":false,"allowAfterThisConstructor":false} should NOT have additional properties.
```

If I strip the rule from its options, I do **NOT** get any error: `"no-underscore-dangle": "error"`. I would prefer to use those two options. What am I missing? Any ideas?

**ESLint version**: 7.6.0
**Node version**: 12.17.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated ESLint to 7.10.0 and now the error is gone:

```
npm i -D eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

3 years later: I updated ESLint from 8.15.0 to 8.55.0 and now the error is gone.