# Lint rule "no-restricted-imports" throw error when patterns group specified

Tags: eslint, nrwl-nx, typescript-eslint

I configured `.eslintrc.json` in Nx/nrwl monorepo for React project. When I add `group` to `pattern` attribute to `no-restricted-import`

```json
"rules": {
    "no-restricted-imports": [
      "error",
      {
        "patterns": [
          {
            "group": ["lodash/*"],
            "message": "Message"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Eslint shows error

> Configuration for rule "no-restricted-imports"
> is invalid:
> Value {"patterns":[{"group":["lodash/*"],"message":"Message"}]} should be string.
>
> Value {"patterns":[{"group":["lodash/*"],"message":"Message"}]} should NOT have additional properties.

without `group` it works correct.

I mirrored same code shown in documentation [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-imports)

```json
/*eslint no-restricted-imports: ["error", { patterns: [{
    group: ["lodash/*"],
    message: "Please use the default import from 'lodash' instead."
}]}]*/
```

import pick from 'lodash/pick';

[image: lint-error]

Comment: Slightly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64261743/13762264

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15043

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem using eslint in an nx/nrwl monorepo. **Updating eslint to `7.32.0`** resolved the issue for me.

Apparently this was due to a bug in eslint that has since been fixed.

When Nx generated my `package.json`, it locked down the eslint version to `7.22.0`; I had to update the dependency in my `package.json` to `^7.22.0` and then run `npm update eslint` to get the latest version.

Comment: Can confirm, upgrading from 7.25.0 -> 7.32.0 fixed this for me.

Comment: I updated eslint to v8, and found out that this is not working again.